# OpenIddict + postman: The specified 'redirect_uri' is not valid for this client application

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, oauth, openiddict, .net-7.0

**Im unable to run an authentication flow with postman using openiddict**

i get the error:

```
error:invalid_request
error_description:The specified 'redirect_uri' is not valid for this client application.
error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2043
```

Postman parameters:

```
grant_type:authorization
client_id:postman
client_secret:postman-secret
response_type:code
code_challenge:S256
code_challenge_method:S256
//response_mode:form_post
redirect_uri:https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
```

[image]

Code:

**Client (TestData.cs)**

```
    public class TestData : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public TestData(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FaDbContext>();
            await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync(cancellationToken);

            var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();

            if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("postman", cancellationToken) is null)
            {
                await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
                {
                    ClientId = "postman",
                    ClientSecret = "postman-secret",
                    DisplayName = "Postman",
                    RedirectUris = { new Uri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback") },
                    Permissions =
                    {
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,

                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,

                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "api",
                        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code
                    }
                }, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

**Program.cs** *(I'm trying to set up multiple flows)*

```c
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict().AddCore(options =>
{
    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<FaDbContext>();
})
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options
            .AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
            .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
            .AllowPasswordFlow();
        options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/token")
        .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize");
        options.SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfos");

        X509Certificate2 privateKey;
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(builder.Configuration["Auth:PrivateKeyPath"]);
        privateKey = new X509Certificate2(bytes, "test");
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2 encryptionKey;
        var bytes2 = File.ReadAllBytes(builder.Configuration["Auth:EncryptionkeyPath"]);
        encryptionKey = new X509Certificate2(bytes2, "test");
        X509Store store2 = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);


        options
        .AddSigningCertificate(privateKey)
        .AddEncryptionCertificate(encryptionKey).DisableAccessTokenEncryption();
        //options.AddSigningKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
        //    Convert.FromBase64String("DRjd/GnduI3Efzen9V9BvbNUfc/VKgXltV7Kbk9sMkY=")));


        options.RegisterScopes("api"); //register permissions

        options
                .UseAspNetCore()
                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough();
        options.AcceptAnonymousClients(); //NOT FOR PRODUCTION
    }
).AddValidation(options =>
{
    options.UseLocalServer();
    options.UseAspNetCore();
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictConstants.Schemes.Bearer;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIddictConstants.Schemes.Bearer;
}).AddOAuthValidation();


builder.Services.AddHostedService<DummyClient>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<TestData>();
```